# Spiting the pandas data frame value into two columns

Tags: string, python-2.7, object, dataframe, split

I have a pandas data frame in which I have to split the product id as shown below:

||  **_id**  ||

|| ProductId-2118-product-chefs-signature-is-our-go-to-kebab ||

||**_id**  || **text** ||

|| ProductId-2118 ||  product-chefs-signature-is-our-go-to-kebab ||

How can I achieve as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like below,read the dataframe and applied a map on top of it assuming always the data after the second underscore is text column

```
data=pd.read_csv("d:\\test.csv")
data["text"] = data["_id"].map(lambda d: d.split("-",2)[2:][0])
data["_id"] = data["_id"].map(lambda d: "-".join(d.split("-",2)[:2]))
```